How to convert a composable to PDF
does anyone know how to generate a PDF from what's displayed on my application's screen? I'm using Kotlin and Jetpack Compose. I need to create a PDF from the visible content of my mobile application. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

There are two ways of generating PDF from the composable one is using Screenshots and one using PDF Element where you have to design a completed pdf using Text,Image,etc

generating a PDF from the visible content of your mobile application in Kotlin using Jetpack Compose can be achieved using several libraries and techniques. One approach is to use the screenshoot manager class available in Android's android.graphicals package to solve this problem that you have.
